# html5 Background Video Full Screen

Tags: css, html, video

im trying to make html5 Background Video in my website . but i have some problem with the IE and Google Chrome .. i have made Live example [HERE](http://mohammadsamy.com/Video/video.html)
Can any one please  tell me what is wrong with my video i found it black screen in Google Chrome and not working in IE
CSS:

```
<section class="container-1140" id="mast" style="height: 775px;">

        <div style="overflow:hidden; background:url(http://riskeverything.us/wp-content/themes/risky/images/splash-home.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:cover;" id="mast_inner-1">

            <div id="mast_inner-2">

                <video loop="1" autoplay="1" id="mast_inner-2" class="_534g" style="display: block;" controls="true">

                    <source src="video/video.mp4"></source>
                    <source src="video/video.webmhd.webm"></source>
                    <img src="video/poster.jpg">

                </video>

            </div>

                </div>

    </section>
```

The HTML is :

```
<section class="container-1140" id="mast" style="height: 775px;">

        <div style="overflow:hidden; background:url(http://riskeverything.us/wp-content/themes/risky/images/splash-home.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:cover;" id="mast_inner-1">

            <div id="mast_inner-2">

                <video loop="1" autoplay="1" id="mast_inner-2" class="_534g" style="display: block;" controls="true">

                    <source src="video/video.mp4"></source>
                    <source src="video/video.webmhd.webm"></source>
                    <img src="video/poster.jpg">

                </video>

            </div>

                </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: Have your tried something like `BigVideo.js`? http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Comment: It works in Chrome for me on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Mahdi ,  i think that we can make it without any JS , please check http://riskeverything.us/

Comment: For accessibility reasons, you should **never autoplay a video**, neither in the background, nor in the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this [plugin](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/demo_bg.html). it is simple and it can solve your task .

Comment: [Please do not post link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: This has nothing to do with copyrights, or whether it's a plugin or something else. This has to do with the content of the answer. Please read the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/213583) to the Meta Stack Overflow question I linked from my previous comment as to why link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. The same information is summarized on the [Stack Overflow help page for writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), under the "Provide context for links" section.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS only, which will work for most browsers

```
#video_background {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 100;
overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

z index should be -100 to make it a background video in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need to `embed ID` of your video which you want to set in your background . Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/bfvopg6p/